# Input method for sumerian cuneiform?

Tags: fcitx

I've recently become interested in learning Sumerian cuneiform. I see there is at least some support in Unicode, and there are fonts in Linux that support the glyphs too, so the question is: is there any support in any input method?

I have looked through the list of what is supported by fcitx (or rather, what is available in Debian), and it doesn't look like it, but it could be - there seems to be a growing interest in learning Sumerian for some reason.